# Make cat interpret input as file (not string)

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, cat, zathura

`cat` has two different behaviours depending on if its input is a string of file. I need to use `cat` to pipe a file to my PDF viewer (Zathura). The file name is based on a modified string with `sed` as follow:

```
cat <(echo test.tex | sed 's/[^.]*$/pdf/') | zathura -
```

I want this one liner to convert a file name string `test.tex` to `test.pdf` and pipe it to Zathura to open the corresponding file. The above command line is not working because the `cat` input is interpreted as a string and not as a file.

Obviously,

```
echo test.tex | sed 's/[^.]*$/pdf/') | zathura
```

is not working, that's why I try to mess around with `cat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you mean:

```
cat $(echo test.tex | sed 's/[^.]*$/pdf/') | zathura -
```

So that the result of your `sed` is an argument to `cat` and not its stdin.

You can also use:

```
cat $(basename $file .tex).pdf | zathura -
```

or

```
cat ${file%.*}.pdf | zathura -
```

Comment: Unbalanced parentheses in the last command.

Comment: Or simpler still, `zathura ${file%.tex}.pdf`.

Comment: @StephenKitt nice short command but I don't understand it's not working on my system... I got the following error: `error: Unknown file type: 'cannot open /home/martin/test/.pdf' (No such file or directory)'`

Comment: @New2OB you need to set `file` to the original file name, as in the last two commands in the answer: `file=test.tex; zathura ${file%.tex}.pdf`.

Comment: Oh I see, it need to use a variable, I was trying to replace `file` by the filename in the command.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend opening a file via `STDIN` with a document viewer that offers features such as automatic document update or SyncTeX. Doing so breaks the link between the original file and the software, since the opened file will be a copy of the original file. The displayed file will actually be something like `/tmp/zathura.stdin`. This can lead to security problems andy when the LaTeX source file is recompiled, the display in the software will not be updated.

So why bother with `cat` when you can simply pass the file name as an argument as follows:

```bsh
zathura $(basename file.tex .tex).pdf
```

or using `sed`

```bsh
zathura $(echo file.tex | sed 's/[^.]*$/pdf/')
```